# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'type' (argparse issue?)

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to write a simple script using python3 and I get this error when attempting to force an arg value to be a string. I've searched around but other threads largely involve using Django, etc, which is not what I'm trying to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('seq_file', type=str, help = 'xyz')
parser.add_argument('sequence_file', type=str, help='xyz')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
File "x.py", line y, in <module>
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('seq_file', type=str, help='xyz')
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'type'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The docs show that [`argparse.ArgumentParser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser)  does not take a `type` argument.

It looks like you are trying to describe an argument in the constructor to `ArgumentParser`.  Use the `add_argument` method to do that.

Change

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('seq_file', type=str, help = 'xyz')
```

to

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('seq_file', type=str, help='xyz')
```